# Are questions about teaching internal programming courses in a corporate environment ontopic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope, questions

I have recently started to teach SQL programming with a focus on the tech-support activities course where I work (an IT Company). While I have good technical knowledge and hands-on experience, I lack any formal teaching knowledge.

Are questions related to such a teaching activity on-topic on this site?

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely, yes.

Bear in mind the audience, however -- we don't have access to your proprietary tool, so you will get the most helpful answers if you should give a clear sense of what concepts you would like help with teaching.

Comment: In my case, the actual tooling is not that important. I will come back with a question about this. Thanks for your quick reaction.